# How to get my other TYPO3 FE templates?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

Although it seems so simple I only get one template in my FE. While the BE-layouts are working fine, I do not get any of my other FE-templates. Only the DefaultTemplate is popping up every time. After trying all kind of samples/ topics read, etc, I’m stuck on this. Here is my set-up.

The TSconfig and PageTS all other files are stored in the extension.

```
# Layout Select box for the FE templates
TCEFORM.pages {
      layout.altLabels.3 =  NewsLetterTemplate
      layout.altLabels.2 =  RedFooterTemplate
      layout.altLabels.1 =  DefaultTemplate
      layout.altLabels.0 =  DefaultTemplate
      removeItems = 4,5,6,7,9,10
     }



###########################################
```

# Config Fluid Template

```
        page = PAGE
        page.typeNum = 0
        page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
        page.10{

        #Path to the template files stored extension
        partialRootPath = {$resDir}/Private/Partials
        layoutRootPath = {$resDir}/Private/Layouts
        file = {$resDir}/Private/Templates/DefaultTemplate.html

        templateName = TEXT
        templateName.stdWrap.cObject = CASE
        templateName.stdWrap.cObject {

        key.data = pagelayout

        default = TEXT
        default.value = {$resDir}/Private/Templates/DefaultTemplate.html

        #Default template
        pagets__DefaultTemplate = TEXT
        pagets__DefaultTemplate.value = {$resDir}/Private/Templates/DefaultTemplate.html

        #Second template
        pagets__RedFooterTemplate = TEXT
        pagets__RedFooterTemplate.value = {$resDir}/Private/Templates/RedFooterTemplate.html

        #Third template
        pagets__NewsLetterTemplate = TEXT
        pagets__NewsLetterTemplate.value = {$resDir}/Private/Templates/NewsLetterTemplate.html


        }

        #Here some variables for use in the template by using {}
        variables {
        siteName = TEXT
        siteName.value = PIZZAWORKSHOP.nl
        pageTitle = TEXT
        pageTitle.data = page:title


        #get the content into the template:
        content < styles.content.get

        #Maincontent
        content_main < styles.content.get
        content_main.select.where = colPos = 0

        #Content Colom 1
        content_column_1 < styles.content.get
        content_column_1.select.where = colPos = 1

        #Content Colom 2
        content_column_2 < styles.content.get
        content_column_2.select.where = colPos = 2
}

   }
```

https://pastebin.com/9TLytchv

Maybe one of you can point me into the right direction here? Thanks.

W.

Comment: Without checking the whole code. `key.data = pagelayout` must be `key.data = pages:layout`

Comment: Changed the key.data =  but the result is still the same (yes emptied all caches). So maybe there is some fault in my code or set-up?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this typoscript `Page TSConfig` on resource tabe in page properties. For this typoscript you can rename defult frontend layout name.

```
TCEFORM.pages {
      layout.altLabels.3 =  NewsLetterTemplate
      layout.altLabels.2 =  RedFooterTemplate
      layout.altLabels.1 =  DefaultTemplate
      layout.altLabels.0 =  DefaultTemplate
}
```

For use different frontend layout like this.

```
[globalVar=TSFE:page|layout=3]
    page.10.template.file = fileadmin/template/shinynewtemplate.html
    page.includeCSS.screen = fileadmin/template/css/style.css
    page.includeCSS.screen.media = screen
[global]
```

Comment: So how to combine this with my config as shown above? Also, I have 3 layout_files.template and some templates like two_columns.html template and partials. 
What I want, is layout1.template which has:
    `<f:render partial="Header" />
<f:render section="Main" />
<f:render partial="Footer" />
`
to be different from layout2.template:
 `<f:render partial="Header" />
<f:render section="Main" />
<f:render partial="Other_Footer" />
` 
In the template/my_template.html I have:
`<f:layout name="layout2" />`

Might be that I am mixing things up here?